# Sufficient and necessary conditions in which $x=0$ is the only zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the quadratic equation

$$ax²+bx+c=0$$

My question is: Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which $x=0$ is the only zero of the above equation.

I think that if $c=0$ then $x=0$ is the only zero

Comment: Our question is: What have you already tried?

Comment: @Pieter21: I think that if $c=0$ then $x=0$ is the only zero

Comment: Well, that is incorrect. If $a = 1, b = 1$, $x = -1$ is also a zero.

Comment: @Pieter21: So, my thought is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition to have $0$ as a root is $c=0$. Trivially $0=a\cdot0^2+b\cdot0+c=c$.
But now, as we want just one real solution to this equation (or two coincident real solutions), we want $x(ax+b)=0$ only in $0$. Thus, $a$ or $b$ must be $0$ (but not both, why?).

In fact, if $a,b\neq0$ then $x=-\frac ba\neq0$ is a root of the equation.
If $a=0,b\neq0$, then $bx=0\iff x=0$.
If $b=0, a\neq0$ then $ax^2=0\implies x^2=0\iff x=0$.

Thus sufficient and necessary conditions to have $0$ as the only root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $c=0$, $a\neq b$, $ab=0$

Comment: Nicely addressed the necessary condition part! And that an only solution can consist of two coincident ones.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

use the fact hat, if $a\ne 0$, than the product of the roots is $\frac{c}{a}$ and the sum of the roots is $-\frac{b}{a}$.

Then look at the case $a=0$.

Comment: Nice hint, but now I'm confused. The question seems high school stuff, that may not yet know this. However, the profile of poster also has questions on Riemann zeta etc.?!

Comment: @Pieter21: Some times, one forgot simple facts about mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

1. $a = 0$. A degenerate case. $bx + c = 0$ has only zero at $x = 0$ for $c = 0$ and $b \neq 0$.
2. $a \neq 0$. You'll find that $b^2 - 4ac$ and $-b$ both have to be $0$. Draw your conclusions from there.